# >>= return ... what's going on here?

Tags: haskell

I was reading a submission on exercism.io in which someone suggested that

```
concat (replicate n str)
```

could be alternatively expressed as:

```
[1..n] >>= return str
```

Without going into all the debate that then ensued on this subject: I'm looking for an explanation in complete layman's terms of why/how this works.

In particular, after trying to recast this in my mind, I thought it might be somewhat analogous to:

```
fmap (return char) [1..3]
```

But what I don't then understand is why

```
[1..n] >>= return 'M'
```

is an error, where

```
[1..n] >>= return "M"
```

is good.

Can any persons who are really clued up in Haskell walk me through how this all works?

Comment: `[1..n] >>= return str` doesn't type-check. `[1..n] >> return str` does, but it is equivalent to `replicate n str`, without the concat. So either way, the premise of your question (that this is a valid substitute) is wrong in the first place.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It does type check - it just requires a `Monad` instance for `(->) r`, which you can get by importing `Control.Monad.Instances`.

Comment: Simpler: `[1..n] >> str`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[1..n] >>= return str
```

Here `return` is from the function monad (`(->) a`) so the above is equivalent to

```
[1..n] >>= const str
```

in which [`const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aconst) is a function that ignores its parameter and always returns `str` and `>>=` is the bind operator for the list monad, which is the same as [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aconcatMap) so we get

```
concatMap (const str) [1..n]
```

which essentially replaces each list element with `str` and then concatenates them.

As to why `[1..n] >>= return 'M'` is an error: it reduces to `concatMap (const 'M') [1..n]` but the parameter to `concatMap` must return a list and `'M'` is not a list, whereas `"M"` (which is equivalent to `['M']`) is.